# TextView settext no effect in Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

[image: textview]

Here's the problem with setting text in TextView in Activity. I guess the problem was that I used the same id for each fragment XMLin another activity. I used the same XML code for relative layout, but all worked well in fragments. The problem with TextView is in another activity. Please have a look at my code :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_main);
    TextView townNameTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.town_name_txt);
    TextView tradeTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.trade_txt);
    String townName1 = "London";
    String trade1 = "buy sum";
    townNameTxt.setText(townName1);
    tradeTxt.setText(trade1);
}
```

and xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_title_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_height"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/town_name_txt"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="@dimen/actionbar_title2"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/side_padding"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/trade_txt"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="@dimen/actionbar_title2"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/side_padding"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

        <org.osmdroid.bonuspack.mapsforge.GenericMapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar_title_map"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

first what I do to fix this: I have change id of TextView. But it hasn't effect.
I tried to delete relative layout in XML, and it deletes from screen. No contact to XML file from Java file.

Comment: Try setting the text from the layout and check if it work from there.

Comment: setting the text from the layout works

Comment: Have you tried changing the id of the textview to something unique so it's not the same as the ids in the fragments? For example change the textview of to activity_town_textview in your xml and change it in the Java to see if it makes a difference

Comment: yes I have tried to change id of textview. It has no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for bothering and thanks to all answers. The problem was a dupplicate setcontentView() method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_main);
    TextView townNameTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.town_name_txt);
    TextView tradeTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.trade_txt);
    String townName1 = "London";
    String trade1 = "buy sum";
    townNameTxt.setText(townName1);
    tradeTxt.setText(trade1);

    setContentView(R.layout.map_main);
}
```

p.s espacially Thanks to Sabya

Answer (score 1):

It is weird that you don't get an exception in this code.

Because there is no method **settext()**. There is method called **setText()**.

Answer (score 0):

Change the method name from **settext()** to **setText()**..

Comment: Your program doesn't contain any error in onCreate(). So I think any other error is there..Can you upload the complete code..?

Answer (score 0):

Case Sensitive problem with method settext() to setText().

Use your onCreate method from this one:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_main);
        TextView townNameTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.town_name_txt);
        TextView tradeTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.trade_txt);
        String townName1 = "London";
        String trade1 = "buy sum";
        townNameTxt.setText(townName1);
        tradeTxt.setText(trade1);
    }
```

Clean and Build project and run it again.
Hope, it will help you

Comment: If I have used settext() the app wouldn't be built. And I cannot show you map screen. OfCourse I'm using setText(). it's typo on stackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running it on Android Lollipop version, Uninstall and re-install the application and check.

Comment: I'm using Android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean and I have 3-5 times uninstalled and re-installed app with rebuildding and restarting android studio with Invalidate caches. but it didn't fix this problem